# Problems creating "select" to choose and show the chosen country

Tags: php

I was watching how to create a php code to show in a  the countries chosen in the column enum type in the database, and in turn show the chosen country by default. 
But it does not show the list of countries to select, it only shows the one I have selected and the rest is blank.

[image: How it looks]

[image]

```php
public static function getAllowFlags(){
    $flaglist = [];

    $flag_q = Db::query('SELECT flag FROM players');
    while($l = $flag_q->fetch_assoc()) {
            $flaglist[] = $l;
    }

    return $flaglist;
}

$AllowFlags = Account::getAllowFlags();

<?php foreach($AllowFlags as $key => $flag) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$flag['flag'];?>" <?=$flag['flag']?'selected':'';?>><?=$flag['flag'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this line is weird ! `<option value="<?=$flag['flag'];?>" <?=$flag['flag']?'selected':'';?>><?=$flag['flag'];?></option>` because it add `selected` if any value is in `$flag['flag']` so every single option is selected !?

Comment: what `var_dump($AllowFlags);` prints ?

Comment: Regarding the first comment, more than I managed to do it that way (even though I do not know if it's wrong). What happens to me is that it captures the option that you have selected by default "that is, you are not returned to the first option of <option> of the select". But the problem is to show the countries that are in the flag column